# Mongo Db update failing while using $Set for a null valued field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update an existing document which has a field with null value in it and I am getting the following error.

**Document:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582299f71e21dbf65027325e"), 
    "b" : "5555",    
    "f" : null
}
```

**Query:**

```
db.getCollection('temp').update({"b":"5555"},{"$set":{"f.1.b":1,"f.2.b":2}})
```

**Error:**

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (f of f.1.b) to traverse the element ({f: null})"
    }
})
```

Why was it not updating the value in the document?

Answer (score 3):

Because there are no `f.1.b and f.2.b` object found to set
In this case you can try this
Prepare a proper object and try to set
Eg :

```
var temp = {
1 : {b: 1},
2: {b : 2}
}
db.getCollection('temp').update({"b":"5555"},{"$set":{f:temp}})
```

Comment: it was working fine if my object is null and In case of having some values already there it will replace existing object. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome.you can tick mark this answer if you got the solution,thanku